# ¿como obtener valores de la DB en la sesion del controlador a la vista y cerrar en cuanto se cierra la sesion?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

esta fue una consulta antigua y saco la idea de la misma(

*necesito llevar esos Values al controlador, me tendria que guardar en  parametros de tipo TiendaParametros junto con las fechas, despues de almacenar en parametros se enviaran a MetodoConsulta(parametros) donde se hara la consulta para retornar el resultado de consulta y luego cargarlo en un pdf.
si hay otra forma de hacer ese ejercicio agradeceria toda informacion, gracias*)

Este es mi vista:

```html
@model Tienda.net.Controllers.Reportes.TiendaParametros

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("TiendaAction", "ControllerTienda", new { id = "PDF" }, FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    
    <fieldset>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FechaInicio)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FechaInicio)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FechaInicio)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FechaFinal)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FechaFinal)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FechaFinal)
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3">
              Colegio<br />
              <select name="singleSelect"class="form-control">
                <option value="1">manzana</option>
                <option value="3">tomate</option>
                <option value="8">zandia</option>
                <option value="9">melon</option>
                <option value="4">naranja</option>       <!-- quiero que toda esta informacion me cargue en una DropDownList -->
                <option value="5">limon</option>
                <option value="2">mora</option>
                <option value="7">frutilla</option>
              </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        

        <p>
            <br />
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>

    </fieldset>
}


@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

este es mi controlador

```
public ActionResult TiendaAction(TiendaParametros parametros, string id)
        {
            LocalReport lr = new LocalReport();
            string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Reportes"), "Frutas.rdlc");
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
            {
                lr.ReportPath = path;
            }
            else
            {
                return View("Index");
            }

            ReportDataSource rd = new ReportDataSource("DTfrutas", MetodoConsulta(parametros).Tables[0]);

            ReportParameter[] parameters = new ReportParameter[2];

            lr.DataSources.Add(rd);
            string reportType = id;
            string mineType;
            string encoding;
            string fileNameExtension;

            string deviceInfo =
                "" +
                "" + id + "" +
                "8.5in" +
                "11in" +
                "0,787402in" +
                "0,787402in" +
                "0,787402in" +
                "0,787402in" +
                "";

            Warning[] warnings;
            string[] streams;
            byte[] renderedBytes;

            renderedBytes = lr.Render(
                reportType,
                deviceInfo,
                out mineType,
                out encoding,
                out fileNameExtension,
                out streams,
                out warnings);
            return File(renderedBytes, mineType);
        }
```

este mi clase TiendaParametros:

```
public class TiendaParametros
{
   public DateTime FechaInicio { get; set; }
   public DateTime FechaFinal { get; set; }
   public int CodFruta { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buenas, espero te ayude

declaras en los controladores que deseas que este la sesion abierta.

```
  public ActionResult Index()
        {

        IList<FrutaModel> fruta = (IList<FrutaModel>)Session["FrutaSeleccionada"];

        ViewBag.idfruta = new SelectList(fruta, "Idfruta", "Nombre");


        return View();
        }
```

Tu modelo fruta:

```
    public class ColegioModel
{
    public int IdFruta { get; set; }
    public string nombre { get; set; }
}
```

la vista:

```
@model SIGA.net.Controllers



@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("ClassController", "MetododelControlador", new { id = "PDF" }, FormMethod.Post))
    {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)


            
                Fruta:
                @Html.DropDownList("IdFruta", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            
    }

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solo renombra tu select a:

```
<select name="CodFruta" id="CodFruta" class="form-control">
```

Con esto, tu propiedad CodFruta de tu modelo TiendaParametros vendrá con el valor seleccionado.

Comment: no logro entender tu mentodo

Comment: Tu controlador recibe un objecto 'parametros' del tipo 'TiendaParametros'. En MVC, los elementos HTML de tu forma, son mapeados automáticamente a las propiedades de tu objecto si es que el nombre del elemento HTML corresponde al nombre de tu propiedad. Así pues, para que tu control reciba el valor de tu elemento html select, su nombre debe de corresponder al nombre de la propiedad de tu objeto.